# Electrostatic potential energy of point-charges at primes up to $x$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Given a positive real (or integral) number $x$ we consider the
electrostatic potential energy of equal point charges at all primes up to $x$
given by
$$E(x)=\sum_{p_1<p_2\leq x}\frac{1}{p_2-p_1}$$
where the sum is over all primes $p_1,p_2$ such that $2\leq p_1<p_2\leq x$.

Very naively, one should expect the contribution
$$\sum_{q<p} \frac{1}{p-q}$$ (where the sum is over all primes $q$ smaller than the prime $p$) of a large prime $p$ to be roughly $\frac{\log p}{\log p}\sim 1$
(since $\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{n}\sim \log p$ and since primes have
density $\frac{1}{\log p}$ in $\{1,2,\ldots,p\}$).

We consider therefore the auxiliary function
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\left(E(x)-\frac{x}{\log x}\right)$$
which we expect (naively) to jitter around $0$. This does not seem
to be the case as shown by the graph of $f$ (plotted at all primes up to $50000$) which seems to be roughly very slowly growing. More precisely,
the graph seems to suggest that $E(x)$ is eventually
$\sqrt{x}s(x)$ times larger than naively expected where $s$ is a function which
increases very slowly.

[[image: Graph of <span class=]$f$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1vgC.gif)

*Can this be explained?*

**Added:** I think I understand the excess (thanks to comments) naively:
Splitting the contribution to the potential energy of a large prime at $\sqrt{p}$ we get
$$\sum_{q<\sqrt{p}}\frac{1}{p-q}+\sum_{\sqrt{p}<q<p}\frac{1}{p-q}.$$
The naive argument assumes that the first sum contributes a proportion of $1/\sqrt{p}$ to the final result but since primes are roughly twice as dense up to $\sqrt{p}$, the small sum up to $\sqrt{p}$ should contribute an excess of order roughly $\sqrt{p}/\log p$. This is indeed what the graph of $f$ suggests. (Agreed, all this is very naive but I am a dedicated worshiper of naive arguments.)

Comment: If you remove all the twin primes from the set of primes then (conjecturally) the relative density in the integers only changes by a lower order term, so your heuristic argument for $E(x)$ would still apply to the modified $E'(x)$, even though $E(x) - E'(x) = \Theta(x/(\log x)^2)$. So there's definitely something fishy even theoretically with the claim that $E(x) \sim x/(\log x)$ with square root cancellation in the error.

Comment: Also, have you tried using some version of the logarithmic integral instead of $x/(\log x)$?

Comment: Your 'naive' approach is a little too naive; a better way to think of it would be to look at $\int_2^n \frac1{n-x}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\log x}$, the appropriately weighted integral of the term in the sum. Note that your approach would also suggest that $\sum_{p\leq n}\frac1p\approx 1$, whereas the actual value is $\Theta(\log\log n)$.

Comment: We have $\sum_{q < p} \frac{1}{p-q} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{p^{n+1}} \sum_{q < p} q^n$, which might be helpful.